# Can I prevent approval workflow task form from redirecting to AllItems inside the Tasks list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have a somewhat modified OOTB approval workflow that works OK, except for one thing. I need the form to just close, or redirect to a custom url once the user clicks on "approve", or any of the other buttons. Users usually open the form directly from the email they receive notifying them about new approval workflow item that needs their attention.

Is this possible to achieve using SPD?